# Dynamic requires with webpack and Angular

Tags: angular, webpack, commonjs

My goal is to have dynamic require without having all the dependencies at the same level bundled, since I may have 50 brands at some point.

My structure would be this one:

```
-src/app
-theming
--default
--brand_1
```

Here is an example Angular component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

const brand = 'brand_1';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [`../../theming/${brand}/style.scss`]
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
}
```

Problem is require creates a map with all the siblings folders and get their content.

```
`webpack:///C:/Users/JeanB/work_projects/playground/angular-advanced-branding/theming ^\.\/.*\/style\.scss$`
…
var map = {
  "./brand_1/style.scss": "../../../../../theming/brand_1/style.scss",
  "./default/style.scss": "../../../../../theming/default/style.scss"
};
```

As you can see, my variable is interpreted as a wildcard, as expected from the [webpack documentation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#require-with-expression).

Would you know how to prevent this from happening?
I see two way out, one is to go with systemJS, which supports dynamic require better.
The other one is more experimental, with the context option for require in webpack.

Any help is appreciated!

-- Update

After a day of research, I came to the fact that Angular does not support interpolated urlStyles values.

Webpack is doing what it should with what webpack gives to it, which is require('blabla' + variable + '.scss').

SystemJs does not have the same behavior, but it's out of scope for now. I'll update the ticket when I have a solution.